# Does NULLIF in Hive have some known implementation issue in certain versions?

Tags: java, hive, null

I'm using EMR 5.19 Hive 2.3.3 and I am having an issue with Nullif not converting from Java String to Hadoop Text or vice versa. The source is the CloudTrail Serde From AWS, it seems solidly written. The issue appears to be from the builtin NULLIF UDF as you can read in the error message:

I'm testing if the result of a regexp extract is an empty string and if so I would like a null, so my column looks a little like `NULLIF(REGEXP_EXTRACT(key,'([^\/]+)(\/\d+)?(\/.*)', 1), '') AS key_prefix` But I'm getting errors as below:

```
2020-02-11 11:06:34,034 INFO [IPC Server handler 26 on 43627] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1574116917806_1754132_r_000008_3: Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error evaluating NULLIF(regexp_extract(_col2, '(^[^\/]*)\/(\d\/)?([^\/][^\/]+)', 1),'')
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:169)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error evaluating NULLIF(regexp_extract(_col2, '(^[^\/]*)\/(\d\/)?([^\/][^\/]+)', 1),'')
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.internalForward(CommonJoinOperator.java:820)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.genUniqueJoinObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:834)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.genUniqueJoinObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:837)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.checkAndGenObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:938)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.JoinOperator.endGroup(JoinOperator.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:196)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableStringObjectInspector.getPrimitiveWritableObject(WritableStringObjectInspector.java:41)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.PrimitiveObjectInspectorUtils.comparePrimitiveObjects(PrimitiveObjectInspectorUtils.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFNullif.evaluate(GenericUDFNullif.java:93)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not direct answer to your question, but hope this will help.

1. `regexp_extract` returns empty string `''` if regex do not match, it can return `null` only if source string is `null`. So, using NULLIF here looks not correct
2. Use double-backslash for shielding special characters like `\\d` in Hive regexp.
3. `/` - is not special character and needs no escaping/shielding.

I would suggest macro like this :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY MACRO normalize_null(s string) CASE WHEN s!='' THEN s END;
```

It will convert empty strings to nulls, NULLs and everything else as is.

Comment: Thanks, for #1 yes, if my regexp doesn't match and returns `''` I want the result instead to be `NULL`, so I'm using `NULLIF`. I had no trouble running the query without `NULLIF`, and I added it because of #1, so though #2 and 3 are valid points… well, the regexp worked. You can see the actual pattern in the log.
I have decided to use a macro for `IF(s='',NULL,s)` instead, and it's working better than `NULLIF`.

Comment: Thanks; and thanks for pointing out `/` isn't special here, as it's much easier to read then.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing NULLIF with a macro that does what NULLIF says it does avoided the exception and worked just as well:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY MACRO NULLIFY(s string) if(s = '', null, s);
SELECT
  NULLIFY(REGEXP_EXTRACT(LSRC.key, '(^[^\\/]*)\\/(\\d\\/)?([^\\/][^\\/]+)', 1)) AS a_schema_name,
  NULLIFY(REGEXP_EXTRACT(LSRC.key, '(^[^\\/]*)\\/(\\d\\/)?([^\\/][^\\/]+)', 3)) AS a_table_name,
  NULLIFY(REGEXP_EXTRACT(LSRC.key, '(^[^/]*)/(\\d/)?([^/][^/]+)', 1)) AS b_schema_name,
  NULLIFY(REGEXP_EXTRACT(LSRC.key, '(^[^/]*)/(\\d/)?([^/][^/]+)', 3)) AS b_table_name,
  NULLIFY(REGEXP_EXTRACT(LSRC.key, "(^[^/]*)/(\d/)?([^/][^/]+)", 1)) AS c_schema_name,
  NULLIFY(REGEXP_EXTRACT(LSRC.key, "(^[^/]*)/(\d/)?([^/][^/]+)", 3)) AS c_table_name,
  NULLIFY(LSRC.key) AS key
FROM (SELECT 'db/1/table/part/file' key) LSRC;
```

Resulted in:

```
db      table   db      table   NULL    NULL    db/1/table/part/file
```

While with a non-matching string:

```
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    non-matching
```

Instead of the inconvenient result with empty strings

```
                                                db/1/table/part/file
```